# How does android room stream query all the data in the table?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I want to upload data to the server through `websocket`, so I am looking for a way to use `Room` to stream query the data in the entire table.

I guess `return List` is not a good solution? Suppose there are 100,000 data in this table, which will consume too much memory.

```kotlin
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>
}
```

Then I found that `Cursor` can be used, the following code has not been tested:

```kotlin
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"))
```

There is a problem, `Cursor` seems to need to manually query each field, that is to say, I also need to build the data class by myself, instead of handing it over to `Room`.

So how should I use `Room` to perform streaming queries on the entire table?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to stream query the data in the entire table using Room, you can make use of the Flow API introduced in Room version 2.2.0. Flow allows you to receive continuous updates as the data changes in the table, without loading all the data into memory at once.

Here's how you can modify your code to use Flow instead of returning a List:

```
kotlin

@Dao 
interface UserDao {    
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user")    
 fun getAll(): Flow<List<User>> 
}
```

By returning Flow<List> from the query method, Room will emit the query results as a stream of List objects. You can observe this stream using Kotlin coroutines and collect the data as it becomes available.

Here's an example of how you can observe the Flow in your code:

```
kotlin

// Assuming you have a UserRepository or ViewModel 
class class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) {    
 fun getAllUsers(): Flow<List<User>> {         
  return userDao.getAll()    
 } 
} 
// In your activity or fragment lifecycleScope.launch {     
userRepository.getAllUsers().collect { 
users ->         
// Process the list of users here         
for (user in users) 
{             
// Handle each user        
 }     
} 
}
```

In this example, getAllUsers() returns a Flow<List>, which you can collect using the collect function from the Kotlin coroutines library. As new data is available, the code inside the collect block will be executed.

With this approach, you don't need to load the entire table into memory at once, and you can efficiently process the data as it is streamed from the database.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Isn't the idea behind flows in Room to support the case of a changing data, and not partitioning the existing result set?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question or the usage of `Room`. `Flow<List<User>>` means that the elements in Flow are `List<User>`, not `User`, so in fact, all the data is queried and placed in `List` at one time.

Comment: This answer, along with the other two you posted, appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: It's likely that GPT, as it often does, misunderstood the question, as @SageJustus pointed out.  This propensity towards bad answers is why we ask that you not use it.